# PySimpleGUI button that adds another slider

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, widget, pysimplegui

I need an "add new group of controls" feature to a control panel built with PySimpleGUI. One selects *which kind* of group of controls each time, so it can't be predefined similarly to what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515789/3904031) to *How to display different layouts based on button clicks in PySimple GUI? (Persistent window loop)*

For brevity I've abstracted the problem here all the way down to a button that should add another slider each time it is pushed.

I've tried to update using `window.Layout` but this is rejected because it reuses existing objects. I tried a `copy.deepcopy` but that fails as well.

Is there a way to dynamically add a new group of controls (multiple times) specified by selecting from a list of options?

[image: button should add another slider]

---

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

s = {'range': (2,6), 'resolution': 0.2, 'default_value': 5,
     'size': (20,15), 'orientation': 'horizontal',
     'font': ('Helvetica', 8), 'enable_events': True}

layout = [[sg.Slider(**s, key='hi'), sg.Button('Add Slider')]]

window = sg.Window('wow!', layout=layout, background_color="gray",
                   size=(400, 200)) 

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None:
        break
    print(event, values)
    if event == 'Add Slider':
        layout[0][0].Update(value=8.0 - values['hi'])
        layout.append(sg.Slider(**s))
        window.layout(layout)
```

Error message:

```
# UserWarning: *** YOU ARE ATTEMPTING TO RESUSE AN ELEMENT IN YOUR LAYOUT! 
Once placed in a layout, an element cannot be used in another layout. ***`
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using a function?

```
def Btn():
    return sg.Slider(**s)
layout.append(Btn())
```

[Solution on Github](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/51#issuecomment-533877550)

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: I searched your Error and on github were people having the same issue. Someone wrote a function had helped him. I will add the link.

Comment: Oh that's great! Please ping me again when you do; I'm signing off now but I'll be back later. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh here's your ping

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure that explanation is compatible where the effect of one control needs to be to *add more controls* to the layout as I'm trying to do here. It's hard to follow that thread because it spans a year and several versions, and I don't see where the final working code can be found. But I'll try some things along this line.

Comment: The example script at the top of that thread doesn't run for other reasons as well. I have version 4.17 and I get `AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'GetPathBox'` that comment about the function was for version 4.4 and the script was written to run in 4.1